# Eclipse Git - Making changes at the same time

Tags: eclipse, git, github, jenkins, egit

This is probably a noob question, as I only started using Eclipse Git a few days ago.

I was wondering if it was, in any way, possible to have multiple people working on different files in a repository but, when ready to commit, only have one commit for all, instead of one commit per person...?

I was also wondering if there was an option to automatically pull modified files, or a way to update the modified files in every person working in the repository, without making a commit per person first?

I'm asking this because I use Jenkins, and every time a commit is made in GitHub, it immediately starts a build, and it would be very annoying to create a commit per person just because of probably some lines of codes.

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EGit doesn't have a feature for that, but you can work around it by ["squashing" the commits in GitHub](https://github.com/blog/2141-squash-your-commits). Here's how it works:

- Step 1) Create a branch
- Step 2) Make everyone work on that branch until it's time to commit (in your words)
- Step 3) Create a pull request for merging the branch with `master` or whatever branch that is marked as default
- Step 4) Click "Merge pull request" and then do this:

[image]

If you can't find the option to squash-merge, go to the repository settings and make sure the checkbox highlighted in this image is full:

[image]

- Step 5) Confirm squash and merge

Comment: Thanks, that workaround is working fine for what we intended to do :)